# Add static text on flag confirmation form?

Tags: 7, flags

The flag confirmation page works fine with standard fields, but I would like to add a basic description/help text/guidelines text field that is admin-controlled and doesn't show up on the flag form as an editable field per each flagging.

Basically:
Are you sure you want to flag x?
{Flagging Guidelines} <- add
Fields from manage fields show here

flag confirm / cancel

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the hook_form_alter. You can just add markup element to this form with flagging guidelines